# What is the integration architecture used by Github for its web interface?

Tags: architecture, web-applications, integration

I am amazed by the way Github integrates with different systems like Travis. They are separate companies, but yet Travis builds blend seamlessly everywhere in the Github interface.

Yes, i am asking *mainly* about integration on the user interface level, there is enough electronic ink around about service integration.

Usually web interfaces get blended via embeds, like for Disqus. On Github however, seems like the interface parts related to Travis are rendered on the server side. Do they enforce a markup structure, or specific style sheets, or do they require to describe the interfaces with a domain specific language?

Comment: Travis CI has a [public REST API](http://docs.travis-ci.com/api/) which GitHub can use to fetch build state for a branch or pull request.

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: @gnat I have tried building applications with a strong bias towards the front end in order to ease integration because i thought it was the best solution and the way the industry is going towards, but it did not meet my needs because such systems turn to be too complex and unreliable for me